# fullcalendar select time not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using latest fullcalendar plugin version.
I have set my fullcaledar with agendaWeek view

Now when I try to get select time I get +5:30 GMT that is IST
so in calendar if I select 01:00 pm to 01:30 pm than in select event I get as 18:30:00 GMT +5:30 (Indian Standard Time)

I tried to set

```
...
timezone: 'UTC',

ignoreTimezone: true, 
...
```

but it is not working still same issue. How can I get proper selected time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add following code for setting timezone

```
...
timezone: "local",
ignoreTimezone: false,
....
```